# Creating notifications with Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to learn ZF2. I know that there are better methods to create notifications but as I said this is for learning purpose. 
My idea is to save the notifications in the database. This is simple I can do it. My question is about how to show them. I have a partial for the header menu , I want to display them there. 
I dont know if i am on the right track i currently have a view helper which i create via factory.

```
class TestMe extends AbstractHelper
{

protected $html;

public function __invoke($name = 'Unnamed')
{
//        if($this->view->hasIdentity()){
//            $user = $this->view->identity();
//        }
    //$this->testJS();
    return "$name , this is Zend Framework 2 View Helper";
}

protected function htmlIt(){

}

protected function testJS($loggedIn = false){
    $js = '';
    $js .= <<<JS
        alert('test');
JS;
    $view = $this->getView();
    $view->inlineScript()->prependScript($js);
    }

}
```

I know this is nothing but I cant understand what is good an wrong. My idea is to pass ot the view helper an array with notifications for the user and display them. So I need a service for making calls to the database or there is another way?

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 already has an Notification Helper Plugin. Have a Look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html

But if you really want to do it on your own, you may want to create an Controller Plugin http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html.

There is a nice Tutorial for that here: http://lab.empirio.no/custom-controller-plugin-in-zf2.html